# FaceID window behaviour

Tags: swift, ios11, face-id

After unsuccessful attempt of FaceId for two times, pop up window does not auto close. Is there any handler to auto close the FaceId after all unsuccessful attempts or any handler to control the FaceId pop up.

The behaviour of pop up is different than touchId.

Please help.

Code is below:-

```
func authentication() {
        let localAuthenticationContext = LAContext()
        localAuthenticationContext.localizedFallbackTitle = “Failed Authentication”

        var authError: NSError?
if localAuthenticationContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &authError) {

            localAuthenticationContext.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reasonString) { success, error in

                if success {
                     print("Authentication Successful”);


                } else {
                    print("Authentication failure");
                    guard let error = error else {
                        return
                    }
                    let errorMessage = self.errorMessageForFails(errorCode: error._code)
                    print(errorMessage);

                }
            }
        } else {

            guard let error = authError else {
                return
            }
            let errorMessage = self.errorMessageForFails(errorCode: error._code)
            display(errorMessage)

        }
    }
```

Comment: Check you are not looping inside the blocks.

Comment: No, I am not doing it. Edited the question with the code.